# Java generics not recognizing type?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

I have a class `Node` that serves as the abstract class for `DoublyLinkedNode` and `FibonacciNode`.

```
package com.benjamin;

abstract class Node<N, T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private N prev;
    private N next;
    private T data;

    public N getPrev() { return prev; }
    public N getNext() { return next; }
    public T getData() { return data; }

    public void setPrev(N prev) { this.prev = prev; }
    public void setNext(N next) { this.next = next; }
    public void setData(T data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

`DoublyLinkedNode` and `FibonacciNode` extend this class as a way to provide common methods to both implementations.

My issue is that java doesn't seem to recognize the type of `N` as a `DoublyLinkedList` when I pass it in.

```
package com.benjamin;

public class DoublyLinkedNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<DoublyLinkedNode<T>, T>{
    DoublyLinkedNode() {
        setPrev(this);
        setNext(this);
        setData(null);
    }

    DoublyLinkedNode(T data) {
        setData(data);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(getData() != null) {
            return "| " + getData().toString() + " |";
        }
        else {
            return "| ; |";
        }
    }
}
```

In my `DoublyLinkedList` class I get an error saying `unable to resolve method setPrev()` and in many places I get `required: DoublyLinkedList got: Object`

This code was working fine until I decided to unify my implementations of Node.

Comment: What lines cause that error?

Comment: copied your code. No errors here

Comment: The message `required: DoublyLinkedList got: Object` gives a hint that somewhere you are using raw types.

Comment: It isn't such a good idea to attempt to parameterize the base type

Comment: The error stems from my driver class which uses setPrev() and setNext() methods which should be different depending on whether I am using a DoublyLinked node, or a FibonacciNode

Comment: @ernest_k how come its not a good idea to parameterize the base type?

Comment: Type parameters are subject to restrictions. Also, as you have that, extending `DoublyLinkedNode` would not be able to return `ChildDoublyLinkedNode` with `getNext/getPrev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the expectation is to have `ANode.getNext()` and `ANode.getPrev()` strictly return instances of type `ANode` (and not of type `BNode`, `CNode`, etc.). If yes, the following will work:

```
abstract class Node<N extends Node<N, T>, T extends Comparable<T>> {}

class ANode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<ANode<T>, T> {}
class BNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<BNode<T>, T> {}
class CNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<CNode<T>, T> {}
```

---

However, as pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982150/java-generics-not-recognizing-type#comment90914926_51982150), this design will cause problems with the following:

```
class DNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends ANode<T> {}
class ENode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends ANode<T> {}
```

In these cases, `DNode/ENode.getNext()/getPrev()` will return `ANode` instances, since the type constraint has already been set by the parent class.

Comment: How would you recommend to fix this design flaw?  Whats the issue with having multiple nodes? I only want my Node class to have getters and setters for attributes `data`, `next`, and `prev`.  Then how these are handled is up to implementation of  `ANode` and `BNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Your design problem seems to stem from the `N` type parameter in `Node`. Let's first remove the `Comparable` stuff for simplicity:

```
abstract class Node<N, T> {
```

Now if we wanted, someone could define a `DoublyLinkedNode` as

```
class DoublyLinkedNode<T> extends Node<String, T>{
```

The first type parameter is `String`, so our `prev` and `next` fields are both strings. Does that make sense? No, definitely not. The next node in a chain must also be a node.

You'll find that Node only really needs a single type parameter. The `prev` and `next` fields can be of type `Node<T>`:

```
abstract class Node<T> {
    private Node<T> prev;
    private Node<T> next;
    private T data;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

It also seems pretty weird that `setPrev` and `setNext` are both set to `this`. I can easily see that resulting in your program going into an infinite loop.

Comment: I had this before.  The issue is that prev and next arent necessarily nodes.  They are of type `FibonacciNode` or `DoublyLinkedNode`

Comment: @BenjaminKosten If your code has to know the difference between a FibonacciNode and a DoublyLinkedNode, then your design is wrong.

Comment: hmm thanks I didnt think about it that way.  Do you recommend only having a Node class then?